# Is shutting down laptop during Windows 10 update download inadvisable?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10

I have been trying to get Windows 10 update on my PC ever since it was released, but the *"Get Windows 10"* window is still stuck on step two (download- in progress).

Today I clicked on the *"view download progress"* button and it took me to Windows update in the control panel. The download process had failed so I clicked on the try again button. It restarted but since my Internet connection is rather slow it is taking a long time. It been downloading for almost four hours now and it's still only 15% done.

I was going to turn my laptop off as it tends to heat up and my router sometimes needs to be restarted or it won't connect at all. Will doing this effect the update process thats running in the 'background' ? I understand that I might have to start the download again from scratch, but what would you recommend? Also, should I stop the download or is letting my laptop run and eventually sleep the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hibernate, if you can. Hibernate should let you turn off your laptop and resume exactly where you left off. Sleep is a good option too.

Otherwise, the update will restart on the next update check, but part (or all) of the download may be lost. I would not worry about stopping it or other problems.